# Lyxpipe not working

Tags: lyx, jabref, zotero

I am using JabRef 3.8.2 and Lyx 2.2.2 on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena XFCE 64.

I would like to cite from JabRef instead of from Lyx as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148287/lyx-and-jabref-problem#239572).

I cannot find a lyxpipe file.

In Lyx, I have path ~/.lyx/lyxpipe under /Tools/Preferences/Paths. 
In JabRef I have the same path under /Preferences/Paths/Settings for Lyx/Kile/Settings.

Lyx was reconfigured and both Lyx and JabRef have been restarted.

When trying to cite from JabRef I get: Status: Error: verify that lyx is working and that the lyxpipe is valid [home/henk/lyxpipe/.in].

I have the same problem with the Lyx / Firefox Lyz extension combination.

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you have those settings it seems to me that JabRef should be looking for `home/henk/lyxpipe.in`, not `home/henk/lyxpipe/.in`.

Comment: Exactly. Both Lyx and JabRef have a path set to ~/.lyx/lyxpipe. So why does JabRef throw an error for a non-existing file on a path that was not set in either program?

Comment: That is strange. What happens if in LyX you do set it to `/home/henk/lyxpipe/` (which I'm not saying is a solution, but perhaps there's a 5% chance it will magically work).

Comment: One of the JabRef devs here, the tilde in the path could be a problem in JabRef, too.

Comment: Removed tile, replaced with /home/henk/ to set path to /home/henk/lyxpipe, closed and restarted both programs, no improvement. I use OpenJDK Java runtime 8, could that be a problem?

Comment: I have the same problem with the Leez (Zotero)/ Lyx combination ("The specified LyXServer pipe does not exist"). That seems accurate - I cannot find a lyxpipe file, and have no idea how to get one.

Comment: Got it working with `/home/henk/.lyx/lyxpipe` in both Lyx and JabRef.

Comment: @user39444 that's great news. Please post your answer and accept it.